# android chrome 45 html5 audio issue

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, audio

i have some internet radios and i provide them to clients via a web page with html5 audio element. It was working with chrome 33 on android but after the update to chrome 45 everything has stopped working. I can still listen to the stream if i visit ip:port/;stream.mp3 which is actually the value of the src attribute of the source element of the audio element. Has anything changed with the new version of chrome regarding html5 audio? how could i get a feedback of what is going on or print any errors? thank you